# PHP output string and maintain spacing

Tags: php, string, output

I have a string stored like so

```
$text="hello sir, 
this is my house"
```

However when I echo the string it appears as

```
hello sir, this is my house"
```

Is there a way to keep the spacing without using `<br>` or `\r\n`?

Comment: Have you tried [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: @Patrick Q  thanks that works

Comment: Do accept the proposed duplicate then.

Comment: @Patrick Q have done thanks again :-)